# Cannot access wordpress login page after migration

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I just moved a wordpress website from local host to my online server. I changes the home url and site url and everything. 
The website works perfectly fine. I can see the posts, pages everything. I can also see the images.

There is only one problem with the admin panel. When I go to login page url : 
http://www.mysiteurl.com/wp/wp-login.php, 
It redirects me to 
http://www.mysiteurl.com/wp/login/?redirect=http://www.mysiteurl.com

This is now happening on my localhost also. I was already logged in to my localhost, so I can access the admin panel but I cannot log out also.

Please help

Comment: The information about the `.htaccess` should be in the Question too. If the file is empty, refresh the permalinks to actually put the right config in there...

Comment: Never mind. Got my answer. It was a plugin that was creating problems. When I disabled it, everything worked properly

Comment: @technocloud Then please add your solution as an answer here, so that other people can learn from your situation.

Comment: what url you have in wp_options table in database ?

Comment: This was a redirection problem. My browser had cached the redirection

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try checking your .htaccess file in the project root.

You could also open the database export (sql file) and search for the URL to find the offending code.

Comment: I did check my htaccess file, in the root as well as in the wp folder. Both the files are blank. Also, on localhost, I was using default Permalink structure. 
And I manually checked all the tables in the database, there is no connection to this redirection.
I also tried searching in wp-login.php file. Can't find anything

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, first put this in the bottom of your wp-config file to force url location:

`define('WP_HOME','yourSiteUrlHere');
define('WP_SITEURL','yourSiteUrlHere');`

The ONLY thing that worked for me to log in is using the "emergency.php" script. It forces WP to let you in. Go here for more info on making the script: 
http://codex.wordpress.org/User:MichaelH/Orphaned_Plugins_needing_Adoption/Emergency

Answer (score 0):

Please change your url in .sql file

1. Export your database as .sql format.
2. open your database file notepad and search your old url and replace
   with new url.
3. import this database to your new database.

   **Other way**

please rename yor .htaccess file to .htaccess_old